# How to get time difference between two requests

Tags: django

I have a custom django form.

I need to get time difference between two requests of each user request.

I dont want to use any model to store this info.

Do i only left to use sessions ?

Comment: Are you trying to get delta between get request and post request of give form/user? How about in get request store start time in hidden field and then compute the delta in post request?

Comment: i am trying to get time between one form submission to another

Answer (score 0):

One option; create a middleware object and use the cache to store a unique key/timedelta per user